# Laravel where query not working

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I've got this table

### beds

id

name

size

room

status

hotel

created_at

updated_at

I need to filter all beds that belong to a certain room. In order to do so, I've coded this lines.

```
public function index()
    {
        //
        $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
        $data = Input::get('room');
        if( $data ){
            $beds = Bed::where('room', '=', $data )->get();
        }else{
            $beds = Bed::where('hotel', '=', $user->hostel )->get();    
        }

        foreach( $beds as $bed) {
            return $bed->get( array('size','room', 'id') );
        }
    }
```

So, If i give it the room id, it should return me only that room's ones.
The thing is that it's returning all table entries.

Any ideas?

---

UPDATE

Fixed relations and tried this:

```
return Room::with('beds')->findOrFail($data)->beds;
```

Now it gives me the number of items.
How can I get the items?

---

UPDATE

This is the model's code:

```
class Room extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = array('beds', 'price', 'name', 'description','hotel');

    public function beds(){
        return $this->hasMany('Bed', 'id', 'room');
    }
}
```

---

UPDATE

The var_dump for:

```
var_dump( Room::with('beds')->findOrFail($data)->beds );
```

is:

```
int(1)
```

---

UPDATE

So, the final code is the following.

controller

```
public function index()
    {
        //
        $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
        $data = Input::get('room');
        if( $data ){
            $d = intval( $data );
            return Bed::where('room', '=', $d )->get( array('size', 'room', 'id', 'name') );
        }else{
            return Bed::where('hotel', '=', $user->hostel )->get( array('size', 'room', 'id', 'name') );    
        }

    }
```

model

```
class Room extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = array('beds', 'price', 'name', 'description','hotel');

    public function camas(){
        return $this->hasMany('Bed', 'room', 'id');
    }
}
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: I would guess that your `$data` variable isn't getting set properly and your `else` case is triggering, sending back everything. Did you try dumping `$data`?

Comment: Tried. And it's triggering the if. It doesn't get into the else case. I'm thinking it's probabbly because $data is string. But run intval( $data ) instead, and same result

Comment: Curious thing is that when I give a room id with no beds related, it returns empty. But with any that has beds assigned, returns all table entries

Comment: see if the edit to my post helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and see if it works. If not, can you provide the `var_dump` of `Input::get('room')` and the structure of the the beds table?

```
public function index()
{
    //
    $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
    $data = Input::get('room');
    if( $data ){
        $beds = Bed::where('room', '=', $data );
    }else{
        $beds = Bed::where('hotel', '=', $user->hostel );    
    }


    return $beds->get(['size','room', 'id'])->toArray();
}
```

Better yet if you want to get specific beds in a room and you have your relations set up correctly:

```
return Room::with('beds')->findOrFail($data)->beds;
```

EDIT

I saw your update. Are you sure its giving you a number of items, maybe there is one item and the number is the id of it. Can you verify? Please provide a vardump of it if thats not the case. Also can you post your code for the relations in the model?

Comment: Made some tests in phpmyadmin. The problem is that the variable is a string. I'm trying to find a way to turn it into an integer. Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide you table structure and the vardump I mentioned.

Comment: string(1) "2" is the vardump

Comment: and whats the data type of the `room` in the table? varchar? int?

Answer (score 3):

You have quite a few issues in your attempts:

```
return $bed->get( array('size', 'room', 'id') );
// runs SELECT size, room, id from `rooms`
```

so it returns all the rooms (why on earth would you like to do this in a foreach anyway?)

---

```
return $this->hasMany('Bed', 'id', 'room');
// should be:
return $this->hasMany('Bed', 'room', 'id');
```

---

```
protected $fillable = array('beds', ...
public function beds(){
```

this is conflict - you will never get a relations when calling `$room->beds` since you have a column `beds` on your table.

---

that said, this is what you need:

```
public function index()
{
    $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();

    if(Input::has('room')){
        $query = Bed::where('room', '=', Input::get('room'));
    }else{
        $query = Bed::where('hotel', '=', $user->hostel);    
    }

    return $query->get(['size', 'room', 'id']); // given you need only these columns

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following from your model, sometimes it is the problem

```
use SoftDeletes;
```